# Cannot reopen transaction using EntityManger

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i'm trying to open transaction twice using one EntityManager:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorldPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Message message0 = new Message();
        message0.setText("Hi!!");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message0);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        
        Message message1 = new Message();
        message1.setText("Bye!!");

        System.out.println("i'm here");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

and get an exception:

> i'm here
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@31e4bb20 is closed

My guess is: it is not possible to get another transaction from closed EntityManager. However [JPA Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-edr-spec/index.html) says:

> `EntityManager.close` method closes an entity manager to release its persistence context and other resources. After calling `close`, the application must not invoke any further methods on the  `EntityManager` instance except for `getTransaction` and `isOpen`, or the `IllegalStateException` will be thrown. If the `close` method is invoked when a transaction is active, the persistence context remains managed until the transaction completes.

Could someone explain where i'm wrong? doesn't possibility of invoking `getTransaction` mean that i can use this transaction and ivoke transaction's methods?

Thank you.

UPDATE

Thanks for the answers, these are most helpful for me:

1:

> You can use the EntityManager until you call close, yes. There is no
> "reopen" method. Creating an EntityManager is a cheap operation – Neil
> Stockton 13 mins ago

2:

> You can call getTransaction to check if a transaction is active. Yu
> could also close an EntityManager with an active tx (as the docs
> state) and commit after the close). Hence the fact you can call
> getTransaction. – M. Deinum 9 mins ago

Comment: The docs are pretty clear.... *the application must not invoke any further methods on the  EntityManager instance except for getTransaction and isOpen,*... You are trying to persist something with a closed entity manager which isn't allowed. You should only call close on the entity manager once.

Comment: ok, but what i cannot understand is why then i can invoke getTransaction and then cannot use it?

Comment: Why would you close the EntityManager then attempt to call ANY method on it?! let alone try to close it again later on!

Comment: So that means i can use once created EntityManager only once, and after close() method it is not available anymore, despite on possibility to getTransaction again, right? Just want to get the concept  correctly.

Comment: You can use the EntityManager until you call close, yes. There is no "reopen" method. Creating an EntityManager is a cheap operation

Comment: You can call `getTransaction` to check if a transaction is active. Yu could also close an `EntityManager` with an active tx (as the docs state) and commit after the close). Hence the fact you can call `getTransaction`.

Comment: Why would you be able to use it once? You can call `merge`, `persist` as many times you want.

Comment: @M.Deinum i ment that whatever is done before close method is one use. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reality here is that your first close() call is not necessary. What you effectively want to achieve is to have two isolated transactions - perfectly valid. There are two basic ways to do that.

1) commit the transaction, start a new one on the same entity manager instance. An example where I abuse indentation to show how long the entity manager lives:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Message message0 = new Message();
        message0.setText("Hi!!");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message0);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        // no close here

        Message message1 = new Message();
        message1.setText("Bye!!");

        System.out.println("i'm here");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
```

2) close the entity manager and create a new one (which as said in comments is quite cheap)

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Message message0 = new Message();
        message0.setText("Hi!!");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message0);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();


// create new EntityManager
em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Message message1 = new Message();
        message1.setText("Bye!!");

        System.out.println("i'm here");

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
```

Which option you choose depends on the further design of the application feature this is part of; option 1) for example is more cache-friendly and will likely maintain the first level cache in between transactions. This has a risk of cached entities in the cache becoming stale if there is a delay between transactions and the data changes in the datasource, something a call to `em.clear()` in between transactions can resolve.

I tend to go for option 2) when I am implementing transaction batching logic, say: file import logic which pumps in large quantities of records which are to be processed and committed in smaller chunks. In any other case, option 1) usually works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try making the following changes to your code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorldPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Message message0 = new Message();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    message0.setText("Hi!!");
    em.persist(message0);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
EntityManagerFactory emf1 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorldPU");
            EntityManager em1 = emf.createEntityManager();
    Message message1 = new Message();
    em1.getTransaction().begin();
    message1.setText("Bye!!");

    System.out.println("i'm here");

    em1.persist(message1);
    em1.getTransaction().commit();
    em1.close();
```

Try and revert!Once EM is closed you should create/open a new one.

Comment: if you create an EMF multiple times then your application will run very slow!!! Also you are not closing your EMF there either ...